# the size for values of type X cannot be known at compilation time

Tags: rust

I'm trying out Rust and struggling with many basic things such as the errors themselves. I have the following code (using Termion lib, but I'm sure that's irrelevant)

```
extern crate termion;

use termion::color;

static bg_white: color::Bg<color::Color> = color::Bg(color::Rgb(255, 255, 255));
static bg_reset: color::Bg<color::Color> = color::Bg(color::Reset);

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

When I compile this using `cargo run`, I get these errors:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn termion::color::Color + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:5:1
  |
5 | static bg_white: color::Bg<color::Color> = color::Bg(color::Rgb(255, 255, 255));
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn termion::color::Color + 'static)`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-sized>
  = note: required by `termion::color::Bg`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn termion::color::Color + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:6:1
  |
6 | static bg_reset: color::Bg<color::Color> = color::Bg(color::Reset);
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn termion::color::Color + 'static)`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-sized>
  = note: required by `termion::color::Bg`
```

How do these errors come about, and what I can do to resolve them?

Comment: *"= note: to learn more, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait "*

Comment: [`termion::color::Color`](https://docs.rs/termion/1.5.1/termion/color/trait.Color.html) is a trait, making `Color` (or `dyn Color`) a dynamically sized type.

Comment: Use `bg_white: Bg<Rgb> = Bg(Rgb(255, 255, 255))` / `bg_reset: Bg<Reset> = Bg(Reset)` instead. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a4203e0c6f8be9e6e64a34930662bfa4&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: @Shepmaster That's an interesting answer. Seems to me that it should be 100% equivalent, but there's obviously something different. Seems extra things get pulled in somehow by the different use statement?

Comment: That's just because it felt ugly to repeat so much. You can write the [spelled-out version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5b073ce1e0e657ef5da0a407fabf6be7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) as well.